# Firebase Cloud function using multiple projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to have a single cloud function query data from 2 different Firebase projects. I'd want to mirror changes performed in "my-app" project's Firestore to "my-app-backup" project's Firestore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [initialize multiple Admin apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps) in a Cloud function as shown below:

```js
// Initialize the default app
initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);
const otherApp = initializeApp(otherAppConfig, 'other');

const defaultFirestore = getFirestore();
const otherFirestore = getFirestore(otherApp);
```

Here you can use `defaultFirestore` to read from first Firestore project and then `otherFirestore` to write in another.